# How to specify port when running app on nuxt + ts + pm2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pm2

I have a nuxt + ts application that runs via pm2. Everything worked fine until I decided to change nuxt.config.js to nuxt.config.ts. The application started to run on port 3000, although port 4000 is specified in the nuxt.config.ts configuration.

This is my scripts from package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt-ts",
        "build": "nuxt-ts build",
        "start": "npm run build && pm2 start pm2.config.js",
        "stop": "pm2 stop pm2.config.js",
        "generate": "nuxt-ts generate",
        "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "lint": "npm run lint:js",
        "test": "jest"
    },
```

This is my nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default {
    /*
    ** Nuxt rendering mode
    */
    mode: 'universal',
    /*
    ** Nuxt target
    */
    target: 'server',
    env: {
    },
    /*
    ** Global CSS
    */
    css: [
        '~/assets/css/fonts.css',
    ],
    components: true,
    /*
    ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
    */
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxt/typescript-build',
        'nuxt-typed-vuex',
    ],
    /*
    ** Nuxt.js modules
    */
    modules: [
        'nuxt-clipboard2',
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/toast',
        '@nuxtjs/moment',
        '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
        'vue-social-sharing/nuxt',
        'nuxt-i18n',
    ],
    router: {
        linkExactActiveClass: 'link-exact-active',
    },
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en'],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        vueI18n: {
            fallbackLocale: 'en',
            messages,
        },
    },
    /*
    ** Axios module configuration
    */
    axios: {},
    /*
    ** Auth module configuration
    */
    auth: {},
    /*
    ** Build configuration
    */
    build: {
        transpile: [
            /typed-vuex/,
        ],
    },
    server: {
        port: process.env.BASE_PORT || 4000,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
};
```

This is my pm2.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'app',
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
            instances: 1,
            script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: 'development',
            },
            env_production: {
                NODE_ENV: 'production',
            },
            args: 'start',
        },
    ],
};
```